# How do you solve a Heroku app showing an error that no module named "My project name"

Tags: heroku-cli

I am trying to upload my first Django project to Heroku and when I run my app its says this:

```
 2020-06-01T13:39:36.641010+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Personal_Website'
    2020-06-01T13:39:36.641135+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-01 13:39:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-06-01T13:39:36.747848+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-01 13:39:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-06-01T13:39:36.747950+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-01 13:39:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

The Personal_Website is my project name

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying using Heroku CLI
Just install it on your desktop

Comment: Send some screenshot